# Is it possible to create an outline border with radius?

Tags: html, css, outline

I known you can add an outline border with CSS3.

```
outline: 10px solid red;
```

Now I was wondering how I can add also a radius to that outline border.

I have tried this one, but doesn't work:

```
.radius {
    padding: 20px 60px;
    text-transform: capitalize;

    -moz-outline: 10;
    outline: 10px solid red;

    -webkit-border-radius: 40px;
    -moz-border-radius: 40px;
    border-radius: 40px;    
}
```

Comment: Why not just use `border: 10px solid red;`?

Comment: I want to have 2 borders on a object, @daGUY ;)

Comment: @daGUY sometimes it's not possible to use borders. This is the case of `checkboxes` input's.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

[Firefox has a property `-moz-outline-radius`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/-moz-outline-radius), however the request to implement a similar feature in WebKit was [closed as WONTFIX](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=81556).  The plan for the future is to [make the outlines follow the borders](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=593717).

I realize this doesn't help much, but the answer to your question is: currently, no (not in a cross browser way).  In the meantime you should use an alternative approach like the one suggested by thekalaban.

Comment: The WebKit issue in your link has since been reopened, as the spec indicates that the outline should follow the border-radius property.

Answer (score 48):

Try using [CSS-Tricks' Infinite Borders technique](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/multiple-borders/) and applying `border-radius`.

This method will require borders and `box-shadow` and not outline.

[image: Dog with infinite rounded borders!]

```css
img {
    border-radius: 4px;
    /* #1 */
    border: 5px solid hsl(0, 0%, 40%);
    
    /* #2 */
    padding: 5px;
    background: hsl(0, 0%, 20%);
    
    /* #3 
    outline: 5px solid hsl(0, 0%, 60%); */
    
    /* #4 AND INFINITY!!! (CSS3 only) */
    box-shadow:
        0 0 0 10px red,
        0 0 0 15px orange,
        0 0 0 20px yellow,
        0 0 0 25px green,
        0 0 0 30px blue;
    
        
    /* If you could do pseudo elements 
       you could get a few more... */
    
    /* Also, HSL is awesome but don't use it if
       you need super old browser support */
}

body { padding: 50px; text-align: center; }
```

```html
<img src="https://www.randomlists.com/img/animals/chipmunk.jpg">
```

Comment: @MichaelYaeger I used the infinite borders technique linked and added a `border-radius` property to the same selector.  Perhaps that's what the fiddle that 404s did too.

Comment: Please keep in mind that this approach only works with `block`-like elements, but not with line-breaking inline links.

Answer (score 0):

@MichaelYaeger Similar answer to user1685185 but with an updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o036duLs/1/), use `border-radius` and `box-shadow`. This JS Fiddle is shown using a "border" around a circular button (bootstrap), but the same applies an image, etc.