# outline property of input control doesn't respect border-radius

Tags: html, css

I have an input field with border-radius and when it's in focus the outline appears but it has rectangular property. I'm using Chrome. Is this a bug? I don't want to remove outline I just want it to respect border-radius.

Comment: Could you put together a http://jsfiddle.net as an example?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to create an outline border with radius?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14896099/is-it-possible-to-create-an-outline-border-with-radius)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No unfortunately it is not possible to keep an outline that is respecting the border-radius in all browsers.
Instead it would be much easier to remove the outline with `outline: 0;` and adding a custom border or box-shadow with CSS on focus.

Example:

```
input[type="text"] {
 outline: none;
}   
input[type="text"]:focus {
 box-shadow: 0 0 3px blue;
}
```

(http://jsfiddle.net/3cggR/)

Answer (score -2):

```
input[type=text]:focus{
box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 1px orange;
outline:none;
}
```

Comment: Maximus specifically stated that he doesn't want to remove the outline.