# Draw border around input without affecting style, layout or spacing

Tags: css

I use `box-shadow` to draw borders around selected HTML elements (I set class on them when the user selects them by clicking), because it doesn't interfere with the layout (adds no space around the element and doesn't override the element border). Unfortunately `box-shadow` doesn't work on some elements, like `input`s without setting their `-webkit-appearance` to `none`.

Changing the appearance is not an option.

Can I somehow draw a frame around the input without affecting it's style?

- `outline` does not work, because it doesn't show border radiuses correctly
- `border` does not work, because it adds space + overrides any element border. Changing the `box-sizing` to `border-box` is also not an option.

Comment: could you not use a wrapper div? But I don't seem to recall ever having issues with [box shadows on inputs](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/ohuq4por/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using outline doesn't add space for me:

```html
<input><input style="outline:10px solid red"><br/>
<input><input><br/>
```

*(Before this attracts more downvotes, please note the question originally mentioned spacing as the reason `outline` was not suitable)*

Some discussion on `outline` and `border-radius` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14896099/is-it-possible-to-create-an-outline-border-with-radius)

Comment: Sorry my mistake - there was another reason why i ruled out `outline`. See my edit - but on second thought this might be the best (least intrusive) option though.

Comment: Some commentary on outlines and border radius here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14896099/is-it-possible-to-create-an-outline-border-with-radius

Answer (score 2):

you could try applying `border-box` to the element then use `border` styles.

```
input {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;     
    border: solid 1px black;
}
```

Comment: How does this not affect layout?

Comment: the border-box takes into account the  width + padding + border to make the complete size of the element without effecting the set size. so a 100px box with padding, border etc. will remain 100px.

Comment: sorry, but i'm not sure what you mean by selection border?

Comment: you would need to set an explicit size on the element for `box-sizing` to take effect though